# how to pass url using angular js in facebook sharing button

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, facebook

> This is html sharing button which on click share the url given in
>   **data-href**.
>   **Problem:** I want to pass the url according to conditions using angular js.
>   I have stored the url in $scope.sd how to use this in data-href.

I tried by putting data-href="sd" but it didn't work.

```
<div id="fb" class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://sample-env.yqk6qkszsb.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/static/polls/img/icon.png" data-layout="button_count" data-size="large" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse">Share</a></div>
```

> app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
   app.controller('ctrl',function($scope){
      $scope.wish=["Birthday","Makar Shankranti","Valentine Day","Holi","Friendship Day"];
      $scope.show=true;
      $scope.isVisible=false;
      $scope.sd='http://nishantsingh.tk'; // I want to pass this url

      $scope.create = function(name,choice){
            $scope.user=name;
            if(!$scope.user){return $scope.errmsg="Please enter your name";}
            if(!$scope.choice){return $scope.errmsg="Please choose your wish";}
            $scope.show=false;
            $scope.isVisible = true;
            $scope.day=choice;
            if(choice=='Birthday'){$scope.bg={background : 'url(../../static/polls/img/birthday.gif)'}}
            else if (choice=='Makar Shankranti'){$scope.bg={background : 'url(../../static/polls/img/makar.gif)'}}
            else if (choice=='Valentine Day'){$scope.bg={background : 'url(../../static/polls/img/valentine.gif)'}}
            else if (choice=='Friendship Day'){$scope.bg={background : 'url(../../static/polls/img/friendship.gif)'}}
            else if (choice=='Holi'){$scope.bg={background : 'url(../../static/polls/img/holi.gif)'}}
      };
      $scope.anCreate=function(anotherName,choice){
          if(!$scope.anotherName){return $scope.msg="Please enter your name";}
          $scope.user=anotherName;
      };
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `data-href="{{sd}}"`

`<div id="fb" class="fb-share-button" data-href="{{sd}}" data-layout="button_count" data-size="large" data-mobile-iframe="true"><a class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2Fplugins%2F&amp;src=sdkpreparse">Share</a></div>`

Comment: The above answer work very well. But if I am using inside the create function with if condition that if ($scope.choice=='Birthday') then **$scope.sd="http//:nishantsingh.tk";** and using the same method in data-href="{{sd}}", It is not working well so can you suggest some answer.

Comment: it should work even if you change the `$scope.sd` from a function. but if you havent declare it outside the function then ofcourse it doesnt have default value. you can see the example [demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/ywi2latlBe8tQlc8FuDF?p=preview)